# viewpager swipe to a fragment, but flash the origin fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a activity ActivityA, ActivityA have 3 fragment, fragmentA, fragmentB and fragmentC; 
also have a activity-alias ActivityB, the parent activity is Activiy, I do this to have two laucher entrance;
When you click ActivityA in launch, it is going to fragmentA through setCurrentItem, also when you click ActivityB, it's going to FragmentB, this is just like dialer and contacts app in huawei or xiaomi phone;
ActivityA launch mode is singleTask, the purpose is when you click ActivityA in launch, it will clear other activity on ActivityA in back stack, just to display ActivityA.

But if you click ActivityA in launch, it is now display fragmentA, press home, and click ActivityB in launch, it will first display fragmentA, then display fragmentB, even through setCurrentItem(tab, false/*smooth*/) method or customizing Scroller(to make the duration to 0).

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ManageFragment(), "MANAGE");
        adapter.addFragment(new BotsFragment(), "BOTS");
        adapter.addFragment(new OnlineFragment(), "ONLINE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);// If you want to open botsFragment
    }
```